# Find a sequence that tends to a given integer

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Please help me with the following problem.

Let $k$ be the last digit when the student IDs of all members of your group are added together. Think of an example of a sequence (whose terms are not all identical) which has limit $k$ and write down a formula for its $n$th term.

Comment: The idea of imposing a value $k$ dependent on the student is so that the work cannot be copied easily, allowing you to understand this question better. Do you know any sequences that converge?

Comment: If nth term is wanted it has either be a series

Comment: @ArchisWelankar what?

Comment: I only can solve this problem for k=0. The sequence is for example {10,20,30,30,50,60,...} sequence of last digit of the sum is {0,0,0,0,0,...}

Comment: @guest6443 see the answer

Comment: @Daniel. I understand this question differently. If the sequence is for example {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...} then the last digits are {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,...}

Comment: {7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,...} -> {7,4,1,8,5,2,9,6,3,0,7,4,1,8,5,2,9,6,3,0,....}

Comment: Suppose the IDs of members of your group are $11,12,13$. Then $k = \text{ last digit of } 11+12+13 =6$. So You need a sequence that converges to $6$.

Comment: Last digit must have some sort of connection between two terms

Comment: So the first part of question - '''Let k be the last digit when the student IDs of all members of your group are added together" has no sense ?

Comment: It is just to get a value for the limit.

Comment: This part - " Think of an example of a sequence (whose terms are not all identical) which has limit k and write down a formula for its nth term." is absolutely clear for me. But the whole excersise has no sense in my opinion

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

One example, $$x_n = k-\frac{1}{n}$$